# Cannot navigate to a ListBox item after returning from that item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a ListBox which is populated from an XML source and databound to give me the values, I've then set this up to navigate to Relative Uri's when selected.

My problem is that when I use the back hardware button I cannot select the item I have previously selected. I played around and got it to work if I hardcode the back button navigation but I'm sure there's a neater way to resolve this.

Code can be found below and any help would be appreciated.

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <ListBox x:Name="ABCitems" SelectionChanged="ABC_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="432" Height="100">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" 
                               Margin="62,0,0,0" 
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"   
                               Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"
                               Foreground="Black" />
                    <Image Height="50" 
                           Width="50" Margin="0,-50,0,0" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Source="{Binding image}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

XAML.CS

```
private void ABCitems_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ABCitems.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        Menu m = ABCitems.SelectedItem as Menu;

        if (m.extUri.IsAbsoluteUri == true)
        {
            string link = m.extUri.ToString();

            NavigationService.Navigate(
                new Uri("/Web.xaml?link=" + link, UriKind.Relative));
        }

        else
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(m.extUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you are using MVVM pattern on wpf.. but if you want to persist values on views while navigation i think you should start using MVVM pattern.. i have not tried this on WPF but in one of my silverlight app what i have done is to Create a static class that works like a SessionManager using a static Dictionary in it. and on navigating from the view i store the ViewModel to my Session.. and when i come back to my view using back button i try and get the ViewModel from my Session and set it as DataContext again...

```
     public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (SessionManager.Exist("PageViewModel"))
        {
            this.DataContext = SessionManager.Get<Page1ViewModel>("PageViewModel");
        }
        else
            this.DataContext = new PageViewModel();
    }
```

here SessionManager will be a static class contain Dictionary to hold objects.

Hope this could be a good pointer.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not really sure how this would be implemented. FYI I am creating a Windows Phone application so can this even be used?

I figured it was simply a matter of reloading the page when the GoBack method is used (from the hardware buttons).

Let me know what you think, and any place I can go to research this. Appreciate your prompt reply!

Cheers,

Carl